# How to swap the y axis of a combination chart from left to right in python openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

How do you change the y axis scale on a combination chart?
I have a Stacked Bar with a second line chart. I'd like the stacked bar y axis to be on the left and the second line chart to have the scale on the right. So this would be a swap for both y axis.

Here is my chart :

```
    chart1 = BarChart()
chart1.type = "col"
chart1.style = 12
chart1.grouping = "stacked"
chart1.overlap = 100

chart1.layout = Layout(
    ManualLayout(
    x=0.12, y=0.25, 
    h=0.9, w=0.75, 
    xMode="edge",
    yMode="edge",
    )
)
```

...

```
chart2 = LineChart()
chart2.style = 12
chart2.y_axis.axId = 0
```

...

```
    chart1.y_axis.crosses = "max"
chart1 += chart2
    WorkSheetOne.add_chart(chart1, 'A1')
```

Comment: Best bet is to change the order of the charts. The logic for this is hard-coded in the library and difficult to change due to the XML.

Comment: I tried to change the order with:
 chart1.y_axis.crosses = "max"
chart2 += chart1
    WorkSheetOne.add_chart(chart2, 'A1')

But this didn't work until I also changed:
chart2.y_axis.crosses = "max"

And I also had to change the :
chart2.title because the chart1 title was now ignored.

Perfect! Thanks!!

Comment: Glad you got something working. Would you consider submitting an update to the documentation?

Comment: I'd be glad to! No idea how to do it though. Do you have a link?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/pull-requests/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Resolved in comments:

```
Best bet is to change the order of the charts.  
The logic for this is hard-coded in the library and difficult to change due to the XML. – Charlie Clark
```

> 

I tried to change the order with:

> 

```
chart1.y_axis.crosses = "max" 
chart2 += chart1 
WorkSheetOne.add_chart(chart2, 'A1')
```

> 

But this didn't work until I also changed:

> 

```
chart2.y_axis.crosses = "max"
```

> 

And I also had to change the : `chart2.title` because the `chart1.title` was now ignored.

For a bar chart with a single data series I was able to reverse the order with this:

```
    chart.x_axis.scaling.orientation = "maxMin"
    chart.y_axis.scaling.orientation = "minMax"
```